# django cms custom app page endless redirect

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am building a website using Django-cms and I code my own Django app (request_quote)

The error I have is that when I try to access an url defined in request_quote.urls.py , it gets stuck in an endless loop but a Django-cms created page works well

I did everything as in http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/extending_cms/extending_examples.html

The redirects:

> ```
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:36] "GET /en-us/ HTTP/1.1" 200 279593
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:42] "GET /request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:44] "GET /en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:45] "GET /en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:46] "GET /en-us/en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:47] "GET /en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:48] "GET /en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
> [11/Apr/2013 09:55:49] "GET /en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302
> ```
>
> 0
>       [11/Apr/2013 09:55:50] "GET /en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/en-us/request_quote/new/
>   HTTP/1.1" 302 0

My 'request_quote.urls'

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from request_quote import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^new$', views.new, name='new'),
)
```

The 'request_quote. cms_app'

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class RequestQuote(CMSApp):
    name = _("RequestQuote")
    urls = ["request_quote.urls"]

apphook_pool.register(RequestQuote)
```

EDIT:
Part of the error is that the url/view is not found (should be a 404)
Found it by putting random stuff in the url (which generates the same endless loop)

EDIT2:
partly fixed thanks to andrews barret
[django-cms app hook at homepage error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141867/django-cms-app-hook-at-homepage-error/9142118#9142118)

> I basically add a child page to /home named /films, **making sure it's**
>   **not in navigation**, and add the app-hook there as well.

This does not work

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^new$', views.new, name='new'),
    )
```

This Work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
                       url(r'^.*$', 'request_quote.views.new', name='new'),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok fixed by using only 'en' in fallback languages in settings.py

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en',],
        'redirect_on_fallback':True,
        'public': False,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

and set LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

Comment: Having found this earlier would have spared me 2 hours of troubleshooting... :) thanks, pal

Comment: Thank you. It helped me solve a problem I had a long time ago.